# How do I package installed files for Yocto?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I'm trying to create a simple Hello World recipe for yocto and failing.  I'm just trying to create a directory on the root files system and copy a file there.  My recipe layout looks like this:

```
meta-hw
meta-hw/conf
meta-hw/conf/layer.conf
meta-hw/recipes-main
meta-hw/recipes-main/hello-world
meta-hw/recipes-main/hello-world/hello-world.bb
meta-hw/recipes-main/hello-world/files
meta-hw/recipes-main/hello-world/files/hello-world.txt
```

This is my layer.conf:

```
BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \
            ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend"

BBFILE_PATTERN_yoctobsp = "^${LAYERDIR}/"
BBFILE_PRIORITY_yoctobsp = "5"
LAYERVERSION_yoctobsp = "4"
```

This is my hello-world.bb:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Hello world recipe"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "file://hello-world.txt"

do_install() {
        install -d ${D}/hw
        cp ${WORKDIR}/hello-world.txt ${D}/hw/
}

FILES_${PN} += "/hw"
FILES_${PN} += "/hw/hello-world.txt"
```

And this is the output I get from `bitbake hello-world`, telling me I haven't packaged the /hw and /hw/hello-world.txt files, though I thought that's what the `FILES_${PN}` lines were doing.

```
ERROR: hello-world-1.0-r0 do_package: QA Issue: hello-world: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
  /hw
  /hw/hello-world.txt
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
hello-world: 2 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]
ERROR: hello-world-1.0-r0 do_package: Fatal QA errors were found, failing task.
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /data/toradex/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-tdx-linux/hello-world/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_package.130751
ERROR: Task (/home/user/meta-hw/recipes-main/hello-world/hello-world.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
```

I'm not sure what to try next as every example I've found looks basically like this.

Comment: Which version of Yocto are you using? If it is Honister, or newer, you should use `FILES:${PN}` instead of `FILES_${PN}`. Also, make sure you use `+=` operator to extend variables, instead of `=`, which overwrites previous values.

Comment: The = instead of += bug snuck in there at the end.  Switched to FILES: and that fixed it.  I'm building a BSP reference image from a vendor (so everything is installed with the repo tool), so it's not entirely clear which version is actually used, but their website says kirkstone so that makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@skandigraun was right.  I'm using kirkstone so it needs to be `FILES:${PN} +=`